# How to handle special characters that read in as `\u2014' in pyspark

Tags: python, text, pyspark

I'm working on a text manipulation exercise in `pyspark`. I first split the article I've read in into words and noticed that special characters are being brought in as `\u2014` instead of an apostrophe.

What would be the most effective way to clean this up in `Pyspark`?

I contemplated just removing any word with this issue but I don't think that is the most effective solution.

Comment: Why not replace them with a dash `-`: `text.replace('\u2014','-')`. By the way, `'\u2014'` is an en-dash `—`, not an apostrophy.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want that character in your text? It should only display with an escape code when you view the `repr` of the string. If your code has genuine problems with that character, it may also choke on other non-ASCII characters, like accented letters. You should probably fix those problems, rather than trying to strip out the non-ASCII characters.